# Internationalization in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

What are the best practices for internationalization in Vue?

Currently I'm thinking of having a 'strings' object that contains all strings, then a bit of ajax magic to update that strings object based on a json file with translated strings to certain languages.

Anyone got any better ideas? I'm currently having a bit of trouble using my strings approach since the strings object has to be loaded before anything else.

Is there a placeholder functionality for strings in Vue? For example, I have a menu whose entries reside in my vm's data. Is there a way to set that to a static string and then automatically bind that to another string once it exists?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The [vue-i18n](https://github.com/kazupon/vue-i18n) plugin is pretty good. They have [documentation](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/) that follows the standard set by the Vue documentation. The package is kept up to date as well. I would start there.

One thing I like is their support for [single file components](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/guide/sfc.html). You can add an additional tag to the component with component specific translations. Here is the example from their documentation:

```
<i18n>
{
  "en": {
    "hello": "hello world!"
  },
  "ja": {
    "hello": "こんにちは、世界！"
  }
}
</i18n>
```

Comment: If I have a lot of translations, in our case 18, wouldn't they all end up in the same file an this file would become huge? I would prefer to load them when needed instead of adding them to a vue file.

Comment: @burzum It's not necessary to use the tag in the components; it's just an option in case you have translations local to a component.

Comment: This is quite a good plugin, but they keep ignoring pluralization issues.

Answer (score 12):

You might read this [article](https://medium.com/@jamuhl/i18n-frameworks-the-unfair-showdown-8d436cd6f470)...

I would recommend looking into a i18n lib that is ready to be used in different frameworks, i.e. [i18next](http://i18next.com/docs/ecosystem/)

There is some vue libs too: i.e. [vue-i18next](https://github.com/rse/vue-i18next) or [@panter/vue-i18next](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@panter/vue-i18next)

Further you should not only consider that you have to instrument your code (i18n) to get your app/website translated. You should think about the process too - how will you solve [continuous localization](https://medium.com/@adriano_55049/continuous-development-integration-and-localization-continuous-deployment-40ca6b9be771), how you keep track of progress, etc...

For a translation management+ system you might eg. have a look at [locize](http://locize.com) it plays well with all json based i18n frameworks... and provides a lot more than traditional systems.

Answer (score 9):

Another possibility is [vuex-i18n](https://github.com/dkfbasel/vuex-i18n), if you want to use the Vuex store. It defines a method and a filter:

```
{{ 'Item' | translate }}
{{ $t('You have {count} new messages', {count: 5}) }}
```